# .NET FTP to Mainframe - French Characters

Tags: c#, .net, ftpwebrequest

How do I perform FTP on a text file which contains both English and French characters?

The normal FTP convert the French character to junk data. Thats created a lot of confusion at the mainframe side.

```
  byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(ftpFileLocation);
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an encoding issue.

I fixed this by using the below code. You can see, instead of ReadAllByes, I read all the text in string format and converted to specific encoding.

The same logic will be useful in other languages as well.

```
byte[] fileContent = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(ftpFileLocation));
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
```